# How to utilise 2020 Dell XPS 13 9300 Developer edition drivers to install Ubuntu on 2019 Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 7390

Tags: drivers, dell, xps

Last year I bought Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 7390. I bought it with intention to install Ubuntu Linux. To my sorrow, it turns out that Ubuntu was not supported on that model. Specifically, here are the problems I realised:

- camera not working
- fingerprint reader not working
- keyboard hotkeys not working (mostly)
- can't resume from standby
- can't change resolution (everything is tiny, even in GRUB menu)

This year, Dell released a Dell XPS 13 9300 Developer edition with Ubuntu pre-installed on it. By comparing the configurations, I've discovered that the new Developer edition XPS 13 has exact same components as my 2-in-1.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to use drivers and configuration instructions from new 9300 Developer edition to install Ubuntu on my 7390 2-in-1?
2. If yes, how?

Comment: From the look of the compatibility page you are out of luck for the camera and finger print reader. However it does address the resolution (HiDpi) issue https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell/XPS/XPS-13-7390-2-in-1 The fact it has a wiki page is a good sign that someone is working on this.

Comment: @MarkKirby how can then the exact same camera and fingerprint reader models work on the identical 9300?